# Pycharm is generating language errors for Python version 3.6 although interpreter is 3.9

Tags: python, pycharm

The language interpreter is set to a Python 3.9 version:

[image: Python 3.9 interpreter]

But a Python scratch file is being parsed by some kind of 3.6 interpreter:

[image: Complaint about 3.6 language features]

Note that I created in two different scratch files and the same error occurs.  Why would this happen and is there a workaround [short of creating an entirely new project from scratch]?

I am on *Pycharm Professional 2021.3.1*

**Update** based on answer by @TurePaisson he though maybe the `Code is compatible with specific Python` were set. That was a shrewd guess - but turns out I have not set that:

[image]

[image]

**Update** The following snippet can be used to test python3.6 vs 3.8+

```py
x = (y := 3) + 7
```

Comment: Try checking what interpreter you have set in the "run configuration". I think the linter may supersede the Project-wide interpreter version from the `Settings` in favor of whatever run configuration you have currently selected. (This can happen as a convenience in projects where you're mixing snippets of different interpreter versions, because `Settings` `>` `Project` `>` `Python interpreter` is just a general default, you can be switching the "run configuration" on the fly for different modules, so that's the version the linter might be looking for) .

Comment: This question is lacking a snippet that can be copy-paste for convenience. I don't have any version specific snippet at hand to test this.

Comment: @bad_coder Please make that an answer: i will at a minimum upvote for usefulness.  About the snippet:  ```x = (y := 3) + 7```  would be sufficient since it uses the `walrus` operator and python3.6 would not understand it whereas 3.8+ does

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I'll be back after I try this.

Comment: Doesn't happen for PyCharm 2021.2.2 I'm updated to your version...

Comment: @bad_coder I *was* able to produce the scenario by setting the run Configuration to choose python3.6.  So your hunch was correct but your testing had a bug.  If you like - just create the answer with your prose and I can add the screenshots and award to you

Comment: Strange issue, I updated to 2021.2.4 and I can't reproduce this (changing the "run configuration" between Python 3.6 and 3.9 does not supersede the interpreter in `Settings` contrary to my hunch.) However, I can not update to the 2021.3.1 because PyCharm wants to go straight for 2022.1... The "run configuration" trick is undocumented behavior I've picked up on from experience, so there's no guarantee it doesn't change between versions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on @bad_coder 's attempt to fix that will be paraphrased as:

> check the `Run Configuration` for pointing to a different `python interpreter` than the project level one

That fix worked for me:

1. Bring up the `Run [Context menu] | Edit Configurations`

[image]

2. Change the `Python interpreter` to the appropriate one:  Shown below is a case where the interpreter is said to the earlier language level. Go to the dropdown and select a correct [python 3.8+] interpeter.

[image]

Comment: Fun fact: Why do I always use a PyCharm version that's 2 or 3 minor versions behind? Because I updated today and the latest iteration of bugs and regressions just hit me... (I'm already waiting for the next stable release that doesn't affect my workflow.)

Answer (score 9):

In the preferences dialog, search for "versions" and you will find, under Editor/Inspections, an inspection "Code is compatible with specific Python versions" with checkboxes for which versions to check against.

Comment: ah! i vaguely remember something like that - will look now

Comment: I can't find that versions dialog. Please paste screenshot and/or the full Preferences | whatever path

Comment: Now I found it - I am going to update the question. I do not have it set.  I am upvoting your answer anyways since it might well have been the solution to similar cases.

Comment: Oh wait - I made some changes to that dialog and saved and that works. that's a mini bug on Pycharm but in any case this is a workaround. awarding

Comment: hold on- no.. does not work: compiler error on 3.6 language version

Comment: I had to create a new python interpreter (version 3.9). Your idea was v good - so thanks for that.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects you should mark the answer as accepted

Comment: @crissal  This answer did not resolve my problem - thus I did not accept. It is however a *good check to make* thus it was upvoted.

Comment: I've never used this option because it overrides whatever the default IDE behavior is of switching version inspections depending on the interpreter. On the JetBrains bug tracker this option is often used as a way to verify possible linter bugs by forcing it to inspect for a specific version. However, after you're done you may want to switch this off as to not have inspections that mix versions.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up creating a new `python interpeter` with version 3.9 and selecting it for the `project interpreter`. There's clearly some bug within Pycharm that it does not always cleanly switch among interpeters/versions - so starting from scratch is sometimes apparently needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by saying that I tried googling the exact error message and there aren't any significant hits (that's reason alone to post this leaving it as a roadsign):

> "Python version 3.6 does not support assignment expressions"

I tried this with PyCharm versions 2021.2.2, 2021.2.4 and 2022.1 Pro (switching between Python 3.6 and Python 3.9) but I wasn't able to reproduce the exact problem that's shown in the question (I was unable to update to the exact 2021.3.1) and there might be some Project setting that's not obvious.

So I have 2 hunches:

1. It's possible there's something stuck [with the inspection profiles](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2021.3/customizing-profiles.html) since the OP seems to be working from a repository.
2. From experience my next guess would be to try and change the interpreter version of the "run configuration" because it's not stated explicitly in the documentation if it supersedes the project-wide interpreter chosen in `Settings` `>` `Project` `>` `Python Interpreter` for linter inspections. From my tests it currently doesn't but apparently it worked for the OP... Maybe by rebuilding the index and refreshing the background linter process.

Comment: Thanks for the effort - i will upvote for that.   btw I reset the title back to the original. Th change you made  to the title is [quite] misleading as to the purpose of the question.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects sorry about the title, looking at it again I see why it's better this way. Fortunately we have collaborative editing so it was a suggestion.